# Validate if value in input field is an Instagram URL in blade.php

Tags: php, validation, laravel-blade

I am using `blade.php` in my development, and I have a concern in validating if the input is a valid instagram url. I have tried doing this:

```
<form class="search_form" id="apply" action=" method="post">
    @csrf
    <label>
         <input type="url" pattern="https?://.+" required id="instagram" value="" placeholder="Instagram Post URL (Paste Here)">
    </label>
    <div class="flex_box">
         <button class="btn pink applyfnsh_btn" type="button" id="save">Confirm</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**UPDATE** this modal is displayed after validation

```
<div class="applyfnsh_modal">
    <div class="applyfnsh_box">
      <div class="modal_close">
         <img src="../../assets/images/close.png" alt="close">
       </div>
          <p>Success</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**modal.js**

```
$(".applyfnsh_btn").on("click", function(){
    $(".apply_modal").toggleClass("open");
    $(".applyfnsh_modal").toggleClass("open");
});
$(".applyfnsh_modal").on('click touchend', function(event) {
    if (!$(event.target).closest('.applyfnsh_box').length) {
    $(".applyfnsh_modal").toggleClass("open");
    $("body").toggleClass("open");
    }
});
```

location is here

```
<script src="{{ url('/assets/js/modal.js') }}"></script>
```

And by the way, I'm using ajax in saving data to db so that page is not refreshed.

```
<script>
    $(document).on("click", "#save", function() {
        $.ajaxSetup({
          headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
          }
        });
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: '/contest/apply/{{ $contest->id }}',
            data: {url : $("#instagram").val(), user_id: 1, contest_id: {{ $contest->id }} },
            success: function(store) {

            },
            error: function() {

            }
        });
    });
  </script>
```

This isn't working and even processes the data when the button is clicked even if the input is not a url or empty.
Is there a way to do it without making a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here it is :

```js
$(document).on("click", "#save", function() {
    
         var instagramLink = $('#instagramLink').val();
    var pattern = new RegExp('https://www.instagram.com/p/(.+?)', 'g');
    if((instagramLink != undefined || instagramLink != '') &&  instagramLink.match(pattern)){
    
       alert(instagramLink + 'is valid');
        /*
        $.ajax({
            headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            },
            type: "post",
            url: '/contest/apply/{{ $contest->id }}',
            data: {url :instagramLink, user_id: 1, contest_id: {{ $contest->id }} },
            success: function(store) {

            },
            error: function() {

            }
        });
        */
    }else{
       alert('Please Enter Valid Instagram Link');
       $('#instagramLink').val('');
        // show modal
       $('.applyfnsh_modal').modal('open');

    }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    
<form class="search_form" id="apply" action="" method="post">
   
    <label>
         <input type="url" required id="instagramLink" value="" placeholder="Instagram Post URL (Paste Here)" class="form-control"/>
    </label>
  
    <div class="flex_box">
         <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="save">Confirm</button>
    </div>
    
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

update-2 : remove your existing scripts :

```
$(".applyfnsh_btn").on("click", function(){
    $(".apply_modal").toggleClass("open");
    $(".applyfnsh_modal").toggleClass("open");
});
$(".applyfnsh_modal").on('click touchend', function(event) {
    if (!$(event.target).closest('.applyfnsh_box').length) {
    $(".applyfnsh_modal").toggleClass("open");
    $("body").toggleClass("open");
    }
});
```

display modal using this way when it is required to display :

to OPEN MODAL : $('.applyfnsh_modal').addClass('open');

to CLOSE MODAL : $('.applyfnsh_modal').removeClass('open');

so

```
 if (validation successfull){
      // submit form using AJAX
   }else{
      $('.applyfnsh_modal').addClass('open');
   }
```

also create one function to close modal :

```
$(document).on('click','.modal_close',function(){
     $('.applyfnsh_modal').removeClass('open');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this. But my problem now here is my success modal is still displayed even though the url fails. Is there anyway I can't show it if the url is incorrect? Thanks for your help. Please see my update.

Comment: I have added it in my question, please see update :)

Comment: from where your modal is being triggerd to open ? , you have added only HTML code of modal , where is JS code ?

Comment: Should I add it on this php file or in js file?

Comment: this <script> ... script </script> . here

Comment: Yes I will. I'm just having hardtime implementing it.